# How to recursively update / re-index a nested self-referencing table after n children are deleted?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have a nested self-referencing table called **`ListItem`** with the following columns that I've filled with some example data:

```
----------------------------------------
| Id   |   ParentId   |   DisplayIndex |
----------------------------------------
| 1000 |   NULL       |   1            |
| 1001 |   1000       |   1            |
| 1002 |   1001       |   1            |
| 1003 |   1001       |   2            |
| 1004 |   1001       |   3            |
| 1005 |   1001       |   4            |
| 1007 |   1001       |   5            |
| 1008 |   1000       |   2            |
| 1009 |   1008       |   1            |
| 1010 |   1008       |   2            |
| 1011 |   1008       |   3            |
| 1012 |   1008       |   4            |
| 1013 |   1008       |   5            |
----------------------------------------
```

Any node or nodes can be deleted at a given time.

If I deleted nodes `WHERE Id IN (1003, 1004, 1005, 1011, 1012)` my table would look like this:

```
----------------------------------------
| Id   |   ParentId   |   DisplayIndex |
----------------------------------------
| 1000 |   NULL       |   1            |
| 1001 |   1000       |   1            |
| 1002 |   1001       |   1            |
| 1007 |   1001       |   5            |
| 1008 |   1000       |   2            |
| 1009 |   1008       |   1            |
| 1010 |   1008       |   2            |
| 1013 |   1008       |   5            |
----------------------------------------
```

This leaves gaps in my **`DisplayIndex`**.  I now have `1, 5` and `1, 2, 5`.  How can I effectively re-index the **`DisplayIndex`** column to be `1, 2` and `1, 2, 3` like below?

```
----------------------------------------
| Id   |   ParentId   |   DisplayIndex |
----------------------------------------
| 1000 |   NULL       |   1            |
| 1001 |   1000       |   1            |
| 1002 |   1001       |   1            |
| 1007 |   1001       |   2            |
| 1008 |   1000       |   2            |
| 1009 |   1008       |   1            |
| 1010 |   1008       |   2            |
| 1013 |   1008       |   3            |
----------------------------------------
```

I am fairly new to CTEs and know that is the route I probably need to go, but am unsure how to get a number that begins at 1 for each nested level and then auto-increments for each row in that level.

Comment: I assume the deletion cannot make any entry *orphaned* that is with no Id = ParentID?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek - I have an After Delete trigger that deletes all child nodes of the deleted node to handle that scenario.

Comment: wouldn't the `DisplayIndex` of  `1008 |   1000       |   1` be 2?

Comment: @JamieD77 - Yea, you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it seems recursive CTE are unnecessary. Window functions are enough. Every `DisplayIndex` should have its value assigned from the order described by `Id` within each unique `ParentId`:

```
update ListItem
set
  DisplayIndex = NewIndex
from ListItem
  inner join
  ( 
    select
      Id,
      row_number() over (partition by ParentId order by Id) as NewIndex
    from
      ListItem
  ) as S on ListItem.Id = S.Id
```

Here is sample fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9dfe/2

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a champ. I forgot about the `over` clause.